# Where can I find statistics on RSS feed reader market share?

Tags: rss, rss-reader, usage-statistics

I have searched on the internet and cannot find up to date (relevant) statistics on RSS feed reader market share.

Is there any recent research into the percentage market share of different RSS feed readers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find statistical information so I have had to rely on more qualitative sources:

Lifehacker:

http://lifehacker.com/5886059/the-best-news-reader-application-for-linux

Android Quality Index:

http://android.qualityindex.com/charts/19000/top-5-news-aggregator-apps-on-android

The Financial Times recommends these apps:

Flipboard

Google Currents

Livestand

Editions

Zite

Pulse

(Jan 20, 2012 PERSONAL TECHNOLOGY - CHRIS NUTTALL)

These were released in the last year so are fairly relevant.

If I had the time I would monitor usage statistics myself to elicit more empirical information.